# Redshift performance: encoding on join column

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

would encoding on join column corrupts the query performance ? I let the "COPY command" to decide the encoding type.

Answer (score 1):

In gernal no - since an encoding on your `DIST KEY` will even have a positive impact due to the reduction disk I/O.

According to the [AWS table design playbook](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/big-data/amazon-redshift-engineerings-advanced-table-design-playbook-compression-encodings/) There are a few edge case were indeed an encoding on your `DIST KEY` will corrupt your query performance:

- Your query patterns apply range restricted scans to a column that is
  very well compressed.
- The well compressed column’s blocks each contain a large number of values per block, typically many more values than the actual count of values your query is interested in.
- The other columns necessary for the query pattern are large or don’t compress well. These columns are > 10x the size of the well
  compressed column.

If you want to find the optimal encoding for your table you can use the [Redshift column encoding utility](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/tree/master/src/ColumnEncodingUtility).

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Redshift is a column-oriented database, which means that rather than organising data on disk by rows, data is stored by column, and rows are extracted from column storage at runtime. This architecture is particularly well suited to analytics queries on tables with a large number of columns, where most queries only access a subset of all possible dimensions and measures. Amazon Redshift is able to only access those blocks on disk that are for columns included in the SELECT or WHERE clause, and doesn’t have to read all table data to evaluate a query. Data stored by column should also be encoded , which means that it is heavily compressed to offer high read performance. This further means that Amazon Redshift doesn’t require the creation and maintenance of indexes: every column is almost like its own index, with just the right structure for the data being stored.

Running an Amazon Redshift cluster without column encoding is not considered a best practice, and customers find large performance gains when they ensure that column encoding is optimally applied.

So your question it will not corrupt the query performance but not a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of details on this by AWS respondants:
[AWS Redshift : DISTKEY / SORTKEY columns should be compressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52625508/aws-redshift-distkey-sortkey-columns-should-be-compressed)

Generally:

```
DISTKEY can be compressed but the first SORTKEY column should be uncompressed (ENCODE raw). 
If you have multiple sort keys (compound) the other sort key columns can be compressed.


Also, generally recommend using a commonly filtered date/timestamp column,
 (if one exists) as the first sort key column in a compound sort key.

Finally, if you are joining between very large tables try using the same dist
 and sort keys on both tables so Redshift can use a faster merge join.
```

Based on this, i think as long as both sides of the join have the same compression, i think redshift will join on the compressed value safely.