# Redshift performing full table scan even with the sort key used in where clause

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a table in redshift DC28XL cluster with about 527M rows.

I have added specific varchar column (called segment) as my dist key and sort key. each segment has about 4M rows. When I run a simple select with a where clause for one segment `select * from table where segment ='s1';` Redshift always performs sequential scan and takes over 3 minutes.

Can someone help me with ways to avoid full table scan and bring the performance down to 10 seconds or less?

Comment: Are you actually checking against a string? By "each segment has about 4M rows" you mean that there are ~4M rows for each distinct value of `segment`, yea? Note that even if your data is sorted, EXPLAIN will still show a sequential scan---it's just a limited sequential scan; the cost will be different for unsorted data. For e.g. I ran a test to check the difference in execution between filtering BETWEEN two timestamps on a sample set with and without the timestamp being the sortkey, and EXPLAIN showed a 7x speedup. Sorted: cost=0.00..110954.75, unsorted: cost=0.00..700127.12)

Comment: I ran the same test with multiple smaller interval BETWEEN statements (combined with ORs) and saw an even greater speedup of ~40x.

Comment: The way Redshift stores the data is in blocks, and there will be a min/max stored with each block for the sortkey. It will still need to glance at each block, but it will see that the value it's looking for is not within the range of that block, so it will skip it, and so on, until it finds blocks with the value within those ranges. So that's why it's still a sequential scan, even though it's not actually scanning every row.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The segment field is varchar and there are about 4M rows for each distinct value of the segment. Also the table shows high skew though it says the dist style is key based. I ran vacuum and analyze. I still get the same results.

Comment: Alexander, thank you for your inputs. But, as per the design I wouldn't need a range. I only need a particular segment everytime or few segments at a time. Should I drop by sort key?

Comment: I know, I just ran an experiment the other day with ranges and was just reporting my results. The same would be true for filtering by a single segment. I'm pretty sure Redshift does not do binary search on the sorted column, which is what makes other searching faster on indexed databases, but Redshift is massively parallel and can still skip blocks, so it shouldn't be the killer, but I'm not 100% sure. Also, this link may be helpful: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=137610. I don't know enough to help you speed up your query I'm afraid, but good luck!

Comment: In others words, are there ways I can improve the performance for the given scenario?

Comment: Why are you doing a `select *` against 4 million rows of data? Do you actually want all that data back? It might be more realistic to run `select sum(value) where segment = 's1'`, since that matches the type of queries that would normally be run against a data warehouse.

Comment: As per John's comment, one simple way to speed up this query is to select *only the columns needed*, not * (all columns). Redshift is a columnar database so the number of columns selected has significant impact on query performance.

Answer (score 4):

A good rule-of-thumb for Amazon Redshift is:

- Set `DISTKEY` to the column most used in a `JOIN`
- Set `SORTKEY` to the column(s) most used in a `WHERE`

Since your data is distributed by `segment` and you are querying for a single `segment`, all the activity is happening on one slice. Therefore, it is not a very efficient operation.

If this data is frequently using `segment` in a `WHERE` clause, then the `SORTKEY` should be `segment` and something else should be the `DISTKEY` (preferably something used in `JOINs` or, if `JOINs` are not used, then use `DISTKEY EVEN`).

Answer (score 0):

You will likely get better performance if you set the distribution style to even and keep the sort key as segment.  This will spread the data across the slices evenly, but keep the segment values sorted together within the blocks.  You'll get the most parallelization that way and minimize the blocks that need to be read.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nate distribution style should be even.
For performance it is advised not to compress sort keys, you need to use `ENCODE raw`

Check this question answered by a Redshift engineer.

[AWS Redshift : DISTKEY / SORTKEY columns should be compressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52625508/aws-redshift-distkey-sortkey-columns-should-be-compressed)

You can run `ANALYZE COMPRESSION table` to identify which columns should be compressed

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I will try the change today and get back to you.